# Python Script Called from Bash does Nothing

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a weird problem. I am calling a python script within a shell script like this:

```
---filename: dl.sh---
#/bin/bash
...
metaData=`python /var/www/music/getMetaData.py "$artist" "$title" | tail -n 1`
...
```

It is a python script that reads metadata from a json resource. In most cases it is working as desired, filling the variable metaData.

For some cases it simply returns nothing. Even print commands from the python scripts are not being called. It seems to me that the python script simply does not get executed, because when I run the command manually it always works:

```
python /var/www/music/getMetaData.py "Artist Name" "Title Name" | tail -n 1
```

In the cases the script return nothing manually executing

```
echo $metaData
```

results in a empty line.

The first lines of the python script are:

```
---filename: getMetaData.py---
import urllib2
import sys
import re
import datetime

print "Testing Output ..."
```

Not even "Testing Output ..." gets printed in these cases...

Comment: What environment are you in?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41)

Comment: What is the difference between the cases where it works, and where it fails? Different file path, different user (and thus permissions).. etc.?

Comment: Give fullpath to `getMetaData.py` in the script as you do when running the command directly.

Comment: The only difference are the argument parameters, because the artist name and title name are different. The weird thing, is when I manually execute the exact same command and args for the cases where it fails  from the bash script, it works. Also weird that the first print does not even get printed...

Comment: Right after the line that sets metaData put the exact same python command line, and see if you get correct output on the standard output. printf statements for $artist and $title might also be helpful.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner Perfect! Your comment actually lead me to the solution. Putting the command directly after the 'metaData=...' line worked. So I printed the args. And the problem were spaces...
Now I am doing this:
artist=${artist//[ ]/;}
title=${title//[ ]/;}
metaData=`python /var/www/music/getMetaData.py "$artist" "$title" | tail -n 1`

Big Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the passed args... Somehow spaces screw up the call to the python script.

Before:

```
metaData=`python /var/www/music/getMetaData.py "$artist" "$title" | tail -n 1`
```

Now:

```
artist=${artist//[ ]/;}
title=${title//[ ]/;}
metaData=`python /var/www/music/getMetaData.py "$artist" "$title" | tail -n 1`
```

With replacing the spaces with + it works now like a charm! Thx everybody!

Answer (score 2):

Try to change `tail` to `head -1` and see if it starts working. If the last line of the script output is a blank then that is what your overall command (including `tail`) would return.